# How can i restore data from mongodb storage path /var/lib/mongodb/

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-recovery, mongorestore

I recently lost my mongodb data and do not have a backup. How can I restore data from mongodb dbPath having following content?

$ ls /var/lib/mongodb/

costats.0  costats-dev.0  costats-dev.ns  costats.ns  internalcrm.0  internalcrm.ns  journal  local.0  local.ns  loopback.0  loopback.1  loopback.ns  mongod.lock  placeholder.0  placeholder.ns  storage.bson  _tmp

i want to restore data from loopback.0. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

If your data files are not deleted

`mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/`

This will start mongodb server with all your data. If data was curropted somehow, you can add `--repair` option

`mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --repair`

Answer (score 0):

have u checked [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore) ? I guess that if u have the xyz.0 db file it allows you to restore database thru above command.

Answer (score 0):

This command facilitates restoration but may be time-consuming:

```
sudo mongod --verbose --port 27017 --bind_ip 10.0.0.1 --keyFile /key_pair.pem --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /db/data/ --repair --directoryperdb
```

For further details, refer to the [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#core-options).